# Having trouble understanding Haskell's type system

Tags: haskell, types, constructor, overloading, algebraic-data-types

I am currently trying to do [20 Intermediate Haskell Exercises](http://blog.tmorris.net/20-intermediate-haskell-exercises/). I was able to get done with the 1st 3 exercises (but this is because `furry` == `fmap` and [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) has those implementations already). I am currently stuck on the instance that says:

```
instance Fluffy (EitherLeft t) where                                        
  furry = error "todo"
```

I am not really understanding what to do. In Learn You Haskell they have a `newtype` variable called `Pair` which takes in a tuple. They then can do pattern matching as such:

```
  fmap f (Pair (x,y)) = Pair (f x, y)
```

I was thinking maybe you could do something similar in my situation:

```
  furry f (EitherLeft (Either a b)) = EitherLeft (Either (f a) b)
```

But, that doesn't work:

```
Not in scope: data constructor `Either'
```

I was thinking maybe I would `import Data.Either` because there might be some import things he has I don't have. But that didn't matter.

I also tried to get just this to work:

```
  furry f (EitherLeft a b) = error "todo"
```

But that doesn't work either:

```
Constructor `EitherLeft' should have 1 argument, but has been given 2
```

I couldn't get this to work either:

```
  furry f (Right x) = (Right f x)
  furry f (Left x) = Left x
```

Which gave the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `EitherLeft t a'
            with actual type `Either t0 t1'
```

I have only been able to get:

```
  furry f (EitherLeft t) = error "todo"
```

to work. But I have no idea what to do with `t`.

I don't necessarily want an answer. I just need a hint as to what to do because I'm reading and I can sort of, understand the examples but I can't really get my head around to coding this stuff right on my own.

Thanks Dan, this is what I came up with for my solution:

```
instance Fluffy (EitherLeft t) where                     
  furry f (EitherLeft (Left x)) = EitherLeft $ Left  (f x)                   
  furry f (EitherLeft (Right x)) = EitherLeft $ Right x
```

Comment: it can be confusing keeping straight the difference between type names and constructor names at first, so here's a rule: in a type definition `data Foo = Foo` the capitalized name to the *left* of the `=` *only* ever appears in type signatures and class instance declarations. The capitalized named to the *right* of the `=` only ever appear in *code*

Comment: I don't think it's good practice to put your solution in the question. It makes it unclear to future readers what you were stuck with, and what you'd already worked out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the Either datatype does not have a data constructor called Either, basically the Either type looks like this

```
data Either a b = Left a
                | Right b
```

So a value can have the type `Either a b` , but there is no value like `Either "one" 1` or something like that, but instead `Left "one"`, or `Right 1`.

So in the case of `EitherLeft`, similarly its values will look like `EitherLeft (Left a)` or `EitherLeft (Right b)`, and need to be pattern matched against as such.